VBA Command Failed on Paste Data to Outlook Body
I encountered an issue with the Paste command in VBA script, where the data fails to paste into the email body. This data not only in Pivot Tables but most likely everything that using Paste,PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText) and others.Currently only 2 errors during this execution, one is Command Failed, second is something related to method locked for editing.
I've tried to use multiple paste option but somehow no solution has been found.
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

Below is the full script for this.
Sub ToSendEmailMorningTime()
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object
Dim MacroWorkbook As Workbook
Dim FILEPATH As String
Dim TargetWorkbookName As String
Dim DateVar As Date
Dim FY As String
Dim subf As String
    
dt = Now()
FY = "FY " & Range("K68")
subf = Format(Date, "yyyymm") & " - " & Range("J70")
FileLocation = "xx\"

'Save Filename
dt = Now()
Filename = Format(dt, "YYMMDD") & "_" & "Internal" & "_" & "checking" & "_" & "XX" & "_" & "Open" & "_" & "Items" & " " & "(" & "1" & ")" & "." & "xlsx"

Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

FILEPATH = FileLocation

TargetWorkbookName = Filename

Set MacroWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FILEPATH & TargetWorkbookName)

'Copy Pivot Table
    Sheets("OpenItems").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Copy

'Date Today and Minus Two
dtToday = Format(Evaluate("Today()"), "DD/MM/YYYY")
dtTodayminus2 = Format(Evaluate("Workday(Today(),-2)"), "DD/MM/YYYY")

newEmail.Display

'Create New Email
With newEmail
    .To = "XX@gmail.com"
    .CC = "XX@gmail.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Open Items as of Statement Date " & dtToday
    .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>XX,<br>" _
    & "<br> XXX <br><br>" & .HTMLBody
    .Display
    
    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    
'To Paste Pivot Table to Selection Body
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = 118
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

    
    .Display
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing

End Sub


I don't know how to update this question, I've tried ChatGPT somehow still no solution, anyone encounter this error before and know the solution?
